# Select between a range

Tags: mysql, select

What is the correct MYSQLI Command to Select from a table only ID's 20-30 or 30-40.  Something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=20 till 30`

Comment: `WHERE ID BETWEEN x AND y`

Comment: I would have imagined this would have been fairly easy to Google

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, i swear to god i couldn't find it..

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables tell that to this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401006/vb-sql-statement-not-selecting-the-correct-row#comment35905720_23401006

Comment: @Matthew, Thanks needed it right now :)

Comment: @DanAndrews -- bonus points for the answer being vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  LittleBobbyTables... *away*!

Comment: @user3570796 be careful swearing to God... especially using "couldn't" vs "didn't".  I believe you **could** find it but **didn't**.  It's usually a predictable ratio of effort vs results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL query could look like either one below. The latter is clearer, though, about whether to include or exclude either limit.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 20 AND 30;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= 20 AND id <= 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id between 20 AND 30`

Comment: -1 for taking someone's answer in a comment and making it your own answer.

Comment: Perhaps I'm late to the game @DanAndrews, but I cannot see the comment to which you are referring, and this does answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to @Matthew's comment.  If so I would suggest that it does not plagiarize as its a complete, albeit, simple answer.